# how to limit box shadow spread not more than parent width and height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, box-shadow

i was wondering if box shadow spread and blur could limited to parent height and width? i am trying using z-index but i doesn't works.. any suggestion?

i have images like this
[image: the image]

is it possible to limit the spread not over the edges of images? thanks for your help..

i was trying to change the index of the div inside the canvas tag (i changed the background image for future cropping)

----------edit answer-------------
HTML

```
<div id="canvas" style="overflow: hidden; width: <?php echo $resolution[0]; ?>px; height: <?php echo $resolution[1]; ?>px; 
         background: url(<?php echo base_url($image_loc); ?>) no-repeat; background-repeat: no-repeat; 
         " class=""></div>
```

JS

```
$('.rectangle').css('box-shadow', '' + 0 + ' ' + 0 + ' ' + '220px ' + '220px ' + '#000');
```

my workflow is when image loaded i started to click the image and create selection with js and aftar the button with icon crop up there clicked it draws the box shadow.. just add the `overflow: hidden`

Comment: show us your code

Comment: i am using javascript for that.. here's the event on js.. `$('.rectangle').css('box-shadow', '' + 0 + ' ' + 0 + ' ' + '220px ' + '220px ' + '#000');`

Comment: edit your question with code

Comment: Just add `overflow: hidden` on your parent div, the parent div should wrap the picture entirely. I agree @לבנימלכה you need to show us your code so it is easier for us to help you (HTML, CSS and JS).

Comment: @PascalGoldbach that's simple answer and super right

Comment: @YosafatKsatria If my comment helped you I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `overflow:hidden` on your parent class.

Here are some examples with `overflow:hidden` :

```css
.wrapper{
/*A little bit of styling on the wrapper...*/
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  float : left;
  padding: 20px;
  border : 1px solid black;
}

.oh
{
 overflow: hidden;
}

.picture{
  padding: 10px;
  border : 1px solid red;
  box-shadow: 0 0 100px 10px  red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper oh">
  <div class="picture">Example with overflow:hidden on the parent class (.wrapper)</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="picture">Example without overflow:hidden on the parent class (.wrapper)</div>
</div>
```

Comment: nice one dude, this is really simple answer